# How to fix my CodeJam 2019-Round1C -Q1 answer

Tags: python

I submitted with the below solution in Python3 during CodeJam.
Yet, it returns WrongAnswer error.

After reading the official analysis, I found the idea does match.
I wish to know which test case/ scenario I have missed!

Link to Google CodeJam: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/00000000000516b9

```py
def result(k, x):
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(k, x))


def select_move(r_set):
    if "P" in r_set and "S" in r_set:
        return "S"
    if "S" in r_set and "R" in r_set:
        return "R"
    if "R" in r_set and "P" in r_set:
        return "P"
    if "P" in r_set:
        return "S"
    if "S" in r_set:
        return "R"
    if "R" in r_set:
        return "P"


def __main__():
    t = int(input())
    for k in range(1, t + 1):
        a = int(input())
        opponents = [input().strip() for s in range(0, a)]

        move = list()
        broke = False
        max_len = 500

        for i in range(0, max_len):
            if broke:
                break
            r_set = set(map(lambda x: x[i % len(x)], opponents))
            if len(r_set) == 3:
                broke = True
                break
            elif len(r_set) == 1:
                # win
                move.append(select_move(r_set))
                break
            else:
                if i == max_len - 1:
                    broke = True
                    break
                move.append(select_move(r_set))

        if broke:
            result(k, "IMPOSSIBLE")
        else:
            result(k, "".join(move))


__main__()
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Is it the robot programming strategy one?

Comment: @tp7 yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program can not find solution for following input:

```
1
2
P
R
```

I assume in your code you are assuming you can win the competition by making right decision at each individual ith letter.
But for example in this specific case what needs to be done (**at least this is how I solved it, there might be other approaches**) is that you must pick P as your first letter (you did this already), than you eliminate some of the teams (here R is eliminated). Now you solve problem again but this time you only try to beat remaining teams after first iteration.

```
1
1
P
```

You concatenate solutions and obtain PS.........

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But there is " We cannot tie an opponent, since that coin flip might not come up in our favor!" in the analysis as well. For the specific case you mention, that's not grantee of a win => IMPOSSIBLE?
Yet, I tried to submit the one that could answer "P" for those cases, still Wrong Answer

Comment: As I said, there is a clear solution such as PS and many other, so it is a guaranteed win. I don't get what exactly your point is.

Comment: I finally got what you mean! Thanks!